# Can't run php spark serve, after upgrading php 8

Tags: codeigniter-4

PHP Deprecated:  Required parameter $userAgent follows optional parameter $body in /media/asus/06D0D488D0D47EFD/Belajar Web/Codeigniter 4/toko-online-ci4/vendor/codeigniter4/framework/system/HTTP/IncomingRequest.php on line 161

Deprecated: Required parameter $userAgent follows optional parameter $body in /media/asus/06D0D488D0D47EFD/Belajar Web/Codeigniter 4/toko-online-ci4/vendor/codeigniter4/framework/system/HTTP/IncomingRequest.php on line 161

CodeIgniter CLI Tool - Version 4.0.4 - Server-Time: 2021-05-10 04:44:31am

An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type:        ErrorException
Message:     Required parameter $from follows optional parameter $verbs
Filename:    /media/asus/06D0D488D0D47EFD/Belajar Web/Codeigniter 4/toko-online-ci4/vendor/codeigniter4/framework/system/Router/RouteCollection.php
Line Number: 1017

```
Backtrace:
                    -365 - /media/asus/06D0D488D0D47EFD/Belajar Web/Codeigniter 4/toko-online-ci4/vendor/codeigniter4/framework/system/Autoloader/Autoloader.php::errorHandler
                            -365 - /media/asus/06D0D488D0D47EFD/Belajar Web/Codeigniter 4/toko-online-ci4/vendor/codeigniter4/framework/system/Autoloader/Autoloader.php::require_once
                            -296 - /media/asus/06D0D488D0D47EFD/Belajar Web/Codeigniter 4/toko-online-ci4/vendor/codeigniter4/framework/system/Autoloader/Autoloader.php::requireFile
                            -258 - /media/asus/06D0D488D0D47EFD/Belajar Web/Codeigniter 4/toko-online-ci4/vendor/codeigniter4/framework/system/Autoloader/Autoloader.php::loadInNamespace
                            -699 - /media/asus/06D0D488D0D47EFD/Belajar Web/Codeigniter 4/toko-online-ci4/vendor/codeigniter4/framework/system/Config/Services.php::loadClass
                            -123 - /media/asus/06D0D488D0D47EFD/Belajar Web/Codeigniter 4/toko-online-ci4/vendor/codeigniter4/framework/system/Config/BaseService.php::routes
                            -696 - /media/asus/06D0D488D0D47EFD/Belajar Web/Codeigniter 4/toko-online-ci4/vendor/codeigniter4/framework/system/Config/Services.php::getSharedInstance
                            -4 - /media/asus/06D0D488D0D47EFD/Belajar Web/Codeigniter 4/toko-online-ci4/app/Config/Routes.php::routes
                            -780 - /media/asus/06D0D488D0D47EFD/Belajar Web/Codeigniter 4/toko-online-ci4/vendor/codeigniter4/framework/system/CodeIgniter.php::require
                            -364 - /media/asus/06D0D488D0D47EFD/Belajar Web/Codeigniter 4/toko-online-ci4/vendor/codeigniter4/framework/system/CodeIgniter.php::tryToRouteIt
                            -312 - /media/asus/06D0D488D0D47EFD/Belajar Web/Codeigniter 4/toko-online-ci4/vendor/codeigniter4/framework/system/CodeIgniter.php::handleRequest
                            -86 - /media/asus/06D0D488D0D47EFD/Belajar Web/Codeigniter 4/toko-online-ci4/vendor/codeigniter4/framework/system/CLI/Console.php::run
                            -57 - /media/asus/06D0D488D0D47EFD/Belajar Web/Codeigniter 4/toko-online-ci4/spark::run
```

Answer (score 1):

https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-77289-page-2.html

> Anyone wanting to use CI4 in PHP 8 should be using the 4.1 branch.
> Latest develop should technically work but it is not advised. Release
> date will have to be determined by the Foundation but in my opinion we
> are ready for 4.0.5 and 4.1, both with PHP 8 support.

That's of  Jan. 6, 2021. You at the very least need to update your CI4 version.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a similar problem that was solved by executing
composer update
at root folder's cmd of the project.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31395553)